# GraphQLHttpClient and CreateSubscriptionStream issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, graphql, graphqlclient, graphql-csharp

I'm developing an application in asp.net core where I have to bind the `GraphQLHttpClient` `CreateSubscriptionStream` data into MVC view (.cshtml) via (xxxxcontroller.cs).

I don't see any code blocks for necessary changes to be done for `Startup.cs` and bind the subscription response to view.

```
var query = new GraphQLRequest{Query = @"subscription { subscribeTest { id name } }"};
var response = _client.CreateSubscriptionStream<object>(query);
```